# Connecting Tableau to Apache Druid

Tags: druid, tableau-api

Can anybody let me know the steps to connect to Apache Druid using Tableau, please?

I tried the steps shown in [this](https://blog.cloudera.com/connect-tableau-druid-hive/) link. But it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: 6 months later, have you found another solution?

Answer (score 0):

I too tried using the Hortonworks Hadoop Hive - way of connecting to Apache Druid from Tableau 2020.3

Since our Druid was on an HDP cluster behind a Knox Gateway, what worked for me was the following settings:

[image: Tableau-Druid Connection Details]

What I noticed is that if you give the http path as "gateway/default/hive", it connects only to hive tables. However if you change that to "gateway/default/llap" which is the setting for HiveServer2 (interactive Hive Server that supports LLAP), then you are able to access of the Apache Druid tables too.

Note that the Tableau Connection Dialog box is slightly different in this version of Tableau compared to the one in the article that you have mentioned.

In case you are trying to connect through Knox gateway, this should help.

Also note that Druid is integrated with Hive in the Hortonworks distribution - HDP. It is on this cluster that this setting worked.