# JDBC Connection between Tableau and Apache Druid

Tags: jdbc, tableau-api, druid

I have been trying to connect to Druid from Tableau using a JDBC Driver.
I have successfully connected using an ODBC Driver as per my answer to this post [Connecting Tableau to Apache Druid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59929124/connecting-tableau-to-apache-druid)

However, I want to be able to use a JDBC driver as well.

Though I have followed the steps in this post: https://support.imply.io/hc/en-us/articles/360025589574-Connecting-Tableau-to-Druid-with-JDBC,

I keep getting the error: "No suitable Driver installed or the URL is incorrect".

As per the article, I have ensured that the avatica driver is downloaded and installed in ~/Library/Tableau/Drivers, as I am on a mac.

I am also sure I am giving the right URL to my broker which I am otherwise able to access on a browser at port 8082.

Any pointers what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the issue may be that you don't have the avatica driver in your classpath. please see https://calcite.apache.org/docs/adapter.html

Comment: Hi Matt, I get that the avatica driver should be in the classpath. According to the the drivers documentation for Tableau, I believe it should scan ~/Library/Tableau/Drivers folder for the driver. Though I placed it there, it is not able to find it. Hence wanted to know hot to make Tableau discover this folder and read the driver from there.

Answer (score 0):

I found from this article: https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/locating-library-jdbc-directory-in-mac-to-install-the-athena-drivers-for-tableau-prep
that Tableau actually looks for the JDBC driver in the ~/Library/JDBC folder on mac (and it does not seem to read from ~/Library/Tableau/Drivers folder as mentioned in the original article in my question). Once I placed the avatica driver in this folder, Tableau desktop was able to find the driver.